# Minimal NGINX configuration for localhost?

Tags: webserver, nginx

I need to serve myself a few static HTML documents for test purposes (playing around with Mozilla add-on development and need content to develop against). I thought I could simply install a lightweight web server, drop in a file or two, and access them over localhost.

I installed NGINX from the repository (Debian), and then navigated to localhost which displayed "Welcome to nginx".

I then added the following block to `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  location / {
    index index.html;
    root /home/rumtscho/localSite/;
  }
}
```

The directory `/home/rumtscho/localSite` exists, and contains the file `index.html`,  but after I saved the config and did `/etc/init.d/nginx reload`, I continue to see the default NGINX greeting page on localhost, not my own `index.html` file.

I also tried removing the location block and dropping the HTML file directly in `/etc/nginx`, but nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the page to display?

Comment: Did you try to clear browser cache?

Comment: There is example configuration in `sites-enabled/default`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you configuration is correct.You may even get rid of the `default_server`, being useless here.

Is your configuration correct/applied?

1. Ensure there is no error at configuration-time

   1. Use `nginx -t` to validate your configuration syntax/grammar
   2. Monitor your error log while issuing `service nginx reload` (or `kill -SIGHUP <master PID>`)
2. Ensure there is no error at run-time by monitoring your error log

Until nothing pops-up, you need to correct your configuration/setup.

Then, if the problem persists, you may ask for more help here, providing details about your setup/configuration and the steps you took.